# Draw a simple table with some cells without a border

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a table

```
  P
Q [A B]
  [C D]
```

where A, B, C, D are drawn with a border. Q and P are labels for the table and should not be drawn with a border. Q and P should be aligned with A.

How to achieve this? I can control which row to draw a border, but it won't help because I can't draw a border for the whole row.

Comment: Have u tried some thing... show us your code so we can help

Comment: What about using nested tables ?

Comment: You have an example? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hmm tables might be a bit messy, using borders with div might be best way to go. It is trivial with it.

Comment: Hang on, I will jsfiddle you in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

td.no-border {
  border: 0;
}

tr.no-border td {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="no-border">
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">p</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="no-border">q</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've created an ad hoc css class helper `no-border`, and applied it only to the cells I want to be borderless.

Comment: thank you... if you think my answer is good enough you could accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Do something like:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>P</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Q</th>
      <td class="border">A</td>
      <td class="border">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <td class="border">C</td>
       <td class="border">D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then use CSS:

```
 td.border { border: 1px solid #000 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is non table solution.

```
    <div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="top">P</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="left">Q</div>
    <div id="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">A</div>
            <div class="cell">B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">C</div>
            <div class="cell">D</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .cell{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
.row{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}
#container{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
}
#top{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#left{
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}

#table{
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:5px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/EUZru/

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution (pure HTML) works for you ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2">P</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErGQk/)